# Custom autoconfiguration with multiple beans of same type

Tags: spring-boot

Using spring-boot-2 I would like to create a custom autoconfiguration that defines a dynamic amount of beans of the same type.

For example I have the following `ConfigurationProperties` to define an `AmazonS3` client

```java
@Setter
@Getter
@ConfigurationProperties("aws")
public class S3ClientProperties {
    private Map<String, S3Config> s3 = new HashMap<>();

    @Setter
    @Getter
    public static class S3Config {
        private String accessKey;
        private String secretKey;
        private String bucketName;
        private String region;
        // ...
    }
}
```

And if I have a yaml like this:

```
aws.s3:
  primary:
    bucketName: bucket1
    region: eu-west-1
  secondary:
    bucketName: bucket2
    region: eu-east-1
```

It would be great to get 2 Bean of the type `AmazonS3` registered to the `ApplicationContext`, one with the name `primary`, one with the name `secondary`.

Is there a more convenient/better way of doing so except having a `@PostContstruct` on my `@Configuration`, autowiring the context and adding those beans manually?

Comment: Some folks might have created that kind of tool, but I doubt that there is standard Spring tool for that purpose.

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58082762/4354956

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ConditionalOnProperty](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnProperty.html) or multiple conditions, simple example (with your `yaml`):

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);

        Map<String, SomeService> someServiceBeans = context.getBeansOfType(SomeService.class);

        someServiceBeans.forEach((key, value) ->
                System.out.println("bean name: " + key + " ,bean class: " + value.getClass().getSimpleName()));
    }

    // some service
    public interface SomeService {

    }

    // service if `aws.s3.primary` property exists
    @Service("primaryService")
    @ConditionalOnProperty("aws.s3.primary.bucketName")
    public static class SomePrimaryService implements SomeService {

    }

    // service if `aws.s3.secondary` property exists
    @Service("secondaryService")
    @ConditionalOnProperty("aws.s3.secondary.bucketName")
    public static class SomeSecondaryService implements SomeService {

    }

    // service if `SomeService` bean missing ( `aws.s3.primary` & `aws.s3.secondary` not exists )
    @Service("defaultService")
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(SomeService.class)
    public static class SomeDefaultService implements SomeService {

    }

    // service with `custom` condition and `class` condition (multiple conditions)
    @Service("customService")
    @ConditionalOnCustom
    @ConditionalOnClass(SomeDefaultService.class)
    public static class SomeCustomService implements SomeService {

    }

    // annotation for custom condition
    @Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Conditional(CustomCondition.class)
    public @interface ConditionalOnCustom {

    }

    // any custom condition
    public static class CustomCondition implements Condition {

        @Override
        public boolean matches(ConditionContext conditionContext, AnnotatedTypeMetadata annotatedTypeMetadata) {
            // do something
            return true;
        }

    }

}
```

application output:

```sh
bean name: customService ,bean class: SomeCustomService
bean name: primaryService ,bean class: SomePrimaryService
bean name: secondaryService ,bean class: SomeSecondaryService
```

Also take a look at [Creating Your Own Auto-configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html)