# Get ConfigurationProperties in ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a `@ConfigurationProperties` POJO. I want to be able to access this inside a `ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar`

```
@ConfigurationProperties("com.some.prefix")
public class VersionProperties {

    private List<String> someList;

    private String someString;
}
```

I have a yaml file with the following properties

```
com.some.prefix:
some-string: test
some-list:
  - v1
  - v3
```

I have an AutoConfiguration class that looks like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(SomeProperties.class)
@Import(SomeImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar.class)
public class SomeAutoConfiguration {

}
```

This [Github Issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2100#issuecomment-66381871) says that making the registrar `BeanFactoryAware` would allow access to the configuration properties bean.

I've done that, but the issue I'm having is that inside my registrar all of the fields of the configuration properties bean are null.

```
@Override
public void registerBeanDefinitions(
        AnnotationMetadata importingClassMetadata,
        BeanDefinitionRegistry registry
) {
    var props = beanFactory.getBean(SomeProperties.class);
    // all of props fields are null here
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was that the `ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar` happens too early in the lifecycle for the `ConfigurationProperties` to be filled in. So, I had to make my registrar `EnvironmentAware` and then use the `Binder` API to fill in the `ConfigurationProperties` POJO.

```
var props = Binder.get(environment)
            .bind("com.some.prefix", SomeProperties.class)
            .orElse(null);
```

Comment: Would you please let me know how you made your registrar environment aware? I am seeing same issue and I can't find anything that is helpful.

Comment: @F.K. `EnvironmentAware` is an interface that your registrar needs to implement

Comment: A minor observation: It only works ― not return null, if there's at leat one property configured.

Answer (score -1):

You can get a bean from srping `ApplicationContext`, or using `@Bean` to inject.

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(SomeProperties.class)
@Import(SomeImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar.class)
public class SomeAutoConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public void XXXX(SomeProperties someProperties) {
        //you can get SomeProperties props here
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue is not getting a bean. The issue is getting the `ConfigurationProperties` bean with its fields set. I can't use `ApplicationContext` in the `ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar` because if I make the registrar `ApplicationContextAware` the `registerBeanDefinitions` method gets called before the application context gets set